# how to get a child(test) and grand child(test) from parent(course) in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need a help, I need to display a child and grand child from `parent id` that means `one id=2` has a `child` `id=3` and `child` `id=3` has a `child` `id=4` (here `child` `id=3` is parent id for `child` `id=4`).

below is my tables:

```
table object_data:

obj_id | type | title 
-------+------+------
3217   |crs   |it 
3221   |grp   |xyz 
3228   |tst   |test 
3264   |tst   |test3

table object_reference:

ref_id | obj_id 
-------+---------
337    |3217       
338    |3221      
343    |3228 
371    |3264


table tree:

tree | child | parent 
-----+-------+------
1    |338    |337 
2    |343    |338 
3    |371    |337
```

from above three tables i need to display like id 3217 has id 3228 and 3264 (need to display only type "tst") I need a query. I am able to write a query for only child id not for grand child. Any one help to sort out this

Comment: please any one help me how to resolve this .am getting grand child (tst) but am not getting both child and grand child at a time

Comment: SELECT
    a.`type` as `parent_type`,
    a.`title` as `parent_title`,
    g.`type` as `gchild_type`,
    g.`title` as `gchild_title`
FROM `object_data` a
JOIN `object_reference` b
    ON a.`obj_id` = b.`obj_id`
JOIN `tree` c
    ON b.`ref_id` = c.`parent`
JOIN `object_reference` d
    ON c.`child` = d.`ref_id`
JOIN `tree` e
    ON d.`ref_id` = e.`parent`
JOIN `object_reference` f
    ON e.`child` = f.`ref_id`
JOIN `object_data` g
    ON f.`obj_id` = g.`obj_id`          this is for to get grand child titile but i need child title also